# Is it possible to mention someone in a code block? discord py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is it possible to mention someone or at least their nickname in a code block embed?

I'm trying to make a leaderboard that outputs an embed with the ranks and all that stuff, I've tried to output the table  without using the code block but it turned out messy so i have to make it in a code block

````
    @commands.command(aliases = ['l'])
    async def leaderboard(self, ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
 
        db = sqlite3.connect('main.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT row_rank , Points, Wins, Loss, Win_Loss_Ratio FROM main ORDER BY row_rank ASC")
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        x = PrettyTable(["Rank","Points","Wins","Loss","Ratio"])
        for row in result:
            x.add_row(row)

        embed = discord.Embed(description = f"\n \n```\n{x}```", color=0xfaa31e)
        embed.set_author(name= f"‎LEADERBOARD")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
````

[image]

Comment: It is possible to add their nickname, but it’s not possible to mention

Comment: and if my memory serves me right to add their nick is by user.nick right?

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning a user in an embed is **not possible**.

If you want you can put the user's nickname and discriminator in the code block with the following usages:

[`User.display_name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.display_name) - Will give the username of the user if he has no nickname on the server, otherwise it'll give the user's nickname.

[`User.discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.discriminator) - Will give the discriminator *(thank you captain obvious)* of a user, basically the 4 numbers after the username.

Have a fantastic day and happy coding ^^

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use `member.mention` in your code

have a good day !